# Pre-Loading Google Glass with .apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, google-glass

So I work as a developer for a startup where we load our inspection software on a pair of Google Glass then we ship the Glass off to a company for them to use.

Our current flow is: setup placeholder account -> setup glass w/ that account -> turn on debug mode -> load .apk -> ship Glass to user, where they replace the account with their own

We would like to be able to either:

1. Reset the device to factory settings after loading the .apk on, but keep the .apk on board, or
2. Skip the setup on the Glass, turn on debug mode, and load the .apk (then when the client gets the glass, the setup tutorial would run for them)

We want this for a few reasons, mainly because the tutorial is helpful to our clients to understand the Glass UI and so we don't have to keep creating placeholder accounts.

If anyone knows a way to do either 1. or 2., I'd really appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you search a way to re-enable the tutorial screens as it seems to be your highest requirement?

Comment: I have. Unfortunately, due to the low adoption rate of Glass, there isn't much out there for resources. Basically, there's Google's official documentation (which is often out of date) and the odd Stack Overflow question here and there.

Answer (score 0):

Is keeping the bootloader in its factory-locked state a requirement?  If not, you could flash a modified userdata image that includes the apk.

Comment: I'll take a look into this when I get back in the morning. Thank you.